# does $(document).ready(function()) execute only after jsp is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, datatables

I am trying to use the datatable jquery plugin to a table that is populated by a JSP . I add the datatable initialisation in the `$(document).ready(function())` but for some reason the plugin is not able to perform the search or pagination . my code snippet is

```
<table class="data-table" id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>value1</th>
            <th>value2</th>
            <th>value3</th>
            <th>value4</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


        <tr>
            <td class="class1"><%= value.valueOne() %></td>
            <td class="class2"><%= value.valueTwo() %></td>
            <td class="class3"><%= value.valueThree() %></td>


            <td class="class4"><%= value.valueFour() %></td>
        </tr>
        <%
        }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function()  {
        alert("HELLO");
        $('#test').dataTable();

       });
</script>
```

Anybody else who has faced this issue , any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Is this loaded using ajax, or just when the main page loads?

Comment: It is loaded when the main page loads .

Comment: Isn't _JSP_ executed server-side? How could something client-side run before something server-side?

Comment: The one thing to check is to see if the java script defining the plugin is loaded at this point. Does it give you an error message if you debug it in developer tools?

Comment: No the Jquery is loaded fine .

Comment: @PaulS.: it's probably a rhetorical question, but (for clarification), no, it can't.

Comment: this execute after DOM loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(document).ready() function is executed when your full page is loaded, no matter where you write it in code.
More info: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/